# How to add tracers to GStreamer in Yocto

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to add GStreamer tracer hooks to my Mickledore Yocto, however to no success.

I add the following line in my local.conf file:
`PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-gstreamer1.0_1.22.5 = " tracer-hooks"`

However it doesn't seem to be enabled once I run:
`gst-inspect-1.0 | grep tracers` on my Yocto Linux.

Comment: Two things: 1. Don't include the version in the `PN` part. 2. The keyword `append` should be at the end of the variable. Try to change the line to `PACKAGECONFIG:pn-gstreamer1.0:append = " tracer-hooks"`

Comment: Adding `append` at the end causes error during build process. However I do agree removal of version is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify the version when using the `OVERRIDES` `pn` way, just set:

```
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-gstreamer1.0 = " tracer-hooks"
```

Before building your image, make sure to verify some stuff that `PACKAGECONFIG` is doing, because for `tracer-hooks` the `PACKAGECONIG` flag is the following:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[tracer-hooks] = "-Dtracer_hooks=true,-Dtracer_hooks=false"
```

Which will make sure that `-Dtracer_hooks=true` goes to `PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS` which is appended to all classes that are related to build systems like `make` and `cmake`, the main are:

- autotools.bbclass: `EXTRA_OECONF:append = " ${PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS}"`
- cmake.bbclass: `EXTRA_OECMAKE:append = " ${PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS}"`
- meson.bbclass: `EXTRA_OEMESON:append = " ${PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS}"`

`gstreamer1.0` recipe `inherit`s `meson`, so check if `EXTRA_OEMESON` got updated:

```
bitbake -e gstreamer1.0 | grep ^EXTRA_OEMESON=

or

bitbake-getvar -r gstreamer1.0 --value EXTRA_OEMESON
```

`EXTRA_OEMESON` will always have one of:

- `-Dtracer_hooks=true` if the flag `tracer-hooks` added to `PACKAGECONFIG`
- `-Dtracer_hooks=false` if the flag is not added to `PACKAGECONFIG`

**NOTE**

Creating a `gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend` file is recommended with the following content:

```
PACKAGECONFIG:append = " tracer-hooks"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I do see `-Dtracer_hooks=true` when I run `bitbake -e gstreamer1.0 | grep ^EXTRA_OEMESON=` however it still seems not to be enabled, since `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep tracers` produces no output. Also is .bbappend file needed?

Comment: I don't know about `grep tracers` part and how to test it, I only helped you checking the enable part, I will check it for you, the `bbappend` is not necessary, it is just recommended to put it in your custom layer rather than `local.conf` to always keep your config saved in one layer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Talel's answer, I also found it necessary to add "coretracers" to the packageconfig flags. The full gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend file becomes this line:

```
PACKAGECONFIG:append = " tracer-hooks coretracers"
```

Yocto then built libgstcoretracers.so into the image. You can run `gst-inspect-1.0` from your compiled image to view the coretracer elements available.

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep tracers
coretracers:  factories (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  latency (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  leaks (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  log (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  rusage (GstTracerFactory)
```